# How to resume a bash session after an ssh disconnection?

Tags: bash, ssh, wget

I connected via ssh to remoute server and started very long wget downloading. Then ssh session was broke, and after reconnect new copy of interpretator was created. Now I see wget process in ps, but is it possible to return control to old interpretator? I know that better solution is to use screen for long commands, but is there other way?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to reattach a process to a different terminal if it's not set up to do that (by way of `screen` / `tmux` / what have you) in the first place.

As a crude approximation, connecting a debugger to the running process may allow you to interact with it in some limited ways, but in this particular scenario, I don't think it will be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the progress of your currently running `wget`, check out the size of the downloaded file, it should be growing. If it doesn't, run `killall wget` and start over.

Next time, consider running `wget --background` to prevent the problem from happening. See the [wget info page](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Basic-Startup-Options).

Answer (score 0):

This command let Wget to work in the background, and write its progress to log file  my.log.
Еhe number of retries 45 (-t options)

```
    wget -t 45 -o my.log http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Google.png &
```